# An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, vscode-extensions, azure-free-services

**New to Azure :** I am using `azure free service` to host `react website` using `vs code` extension `Azure App Service`.
While deploying I am getting following error with no specific details

```
  Using Node version:
  v14.18.3
  Using Npm version:
  6.14.15
  Running 'npm install --unsafe-perm'...
  > react-scripts build
  Creating an optimized production build...
  An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details.
  Deployment failed.
```

**Inside Azure All Service** :- `microsoft.alertsmanagement/smartdetectoralertrules`

Failure Anomalies notifies you of an unusual rise in the rate of failed HTTP requests or dependency calls.

**Steps to reproduce**

- First deployment worked for me
- After adding new dependancy in `package.json` it is not working (previously worked adding same dependancy)
- Adding new png assets to project is failed, every time reason is different of failing

**Trials to solve**

- Deleted projects and re created
- Updated project dependancy
- New project created but its fails after some changes to project

Please help to solve this problem

Comment: Have you ever tried the answer and the suggestions. If the answer is helpful, please mark it as a correct one. If not, we are happy to help you solve the issue.

Comment: I am also having this issue, have you found a fix for this?

Comment: @Sagar is it because of the free service? I am also having this issue, cant deploy new things on my resource.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy directly from VS Code?

Comment: @DreyserEguia yes! Error: "An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details." - No details in the diagnostic log...

Comment: @DreyserEguia yes

Comment: I was able to upload sometimes from VSCode, but then started having this error, tried uploading directly into Azure, tried from github as well no sucess... errors on different parts of the process... so, I ended up switching to firebase, in a few minuts I was able to deploy without any issues from CLI!